# variable scope and javascript execution context

Tags: javascript

I have some trouble to understand the Javascript execution context

see below code:

```
<script >    

  var global_var;
  first();

  function first() {
    var first_var = 'a';
    second();
  }

  function second() {
    var second_var = 'b';

    console.log(first_var);
    console.log(second_var);
  }

  console.log('in the outer');
  //second();  

</script>
```

Based on my understanding, when `first` function call the `second` function, the second function is inside first function's execution context, so, the `second` can also access `first` function's properties, here is `first_var`

But, the actually output in function `second` display "`first_var` is not defined"

I am confused, could some one give me some explanation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scoping is based in the **lexical structure** of the code, not the dynamic runtime relationship between functions (the "thread of execution").  The lexical structure is the static organization of the code; the "nesting" of function inside function.

In your case, the "second" function is declared outside of the "first" function, so the local variable in "first" is not visible to the code in "second".

If you were to move the "second" function inside "first":

```
function first() {
  function second() {
    var second_var = 'b';

    console.log(first_var);
    console.log(second_var);
  }
  var first_var = 'a';
  second();
}
```

then the variable *would* be visible.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has two scopes:  global and function.  (ES6 will introduce block scope with `let` and `const`, but for the sake of discussion, just assume the first two.

What this means is that variables defined in a function are only visible within that function.  This has nothing to do with execution context.

So, in your example, `first_var` is only visible in `first`, `second_var` is only visible in `second`, `global_var` is visible globally because its not defined in a function.

Execution context comes into play with how `this` is defined, but that is another question and another topic entirely.